# When does an agent learn in the Matalb Reinforcement Learning Toolbox?

Tags: matlab, reinforcement-learning, training-data, mini-batch

I'm currently testing the Reinforcement Learning Toolbox in Matlab R2019a. Everything is working well so far, but I stumbled upon a question the documentation couldn't answer satisfyingly:

When does the agent learn?

The documentation says about the minibatch-size

> During each training episode, the agent randomly samples experiences from the experience buffer when computing gradients for updating the actor and critic properties.

The problem is that it is clarified nowhere what exactly is meant by 'training episode'.

Doese the train-function of the RL-Toolbox train the agent **at the end of an episode** or **during the episode when the step count exeeds the minibatch-size** (like in the baseline algorithms)?

I have the following setup for the agent

```matlab
agentOptions = rlDQNAgentOptions('SampleTime',Ts,...
                                 'UseDoubleDQN',true,...
                                 'TargetSmoothFactor',1e-3,...
                                 'DiscountFactor',0.99,...
                                 'NumStepsToLookAhead',4,...
                                 'ExperienceBufferLength',1e6,...
                                 'MiniBatchSize',120,...
                                 'ResetExperienceBufferBeforeTraining', false,...
                                 'SaveExperienceBufferWithAgent',true);
```

with Ts = 0.25.
The length of one episode is set to 2000 steps, because the agent is there to learn his behaviour in a long-running process. It is not possible to make the episodes shorter because otherwise the agent would not meet all the interesting states.

Could maybe someone enlighten me or provide me with a hint how I could double-check?

I had the idea to monitor the epsilon-decay (which occurs after every training), but I have no idea how to do this in a closed fast-restart loop (which already blocks me off from opening another .m-file).

Comment: Please see documentation under [ExperienceBufferLength'](https://www.mathworks.com/help/reinforcement-learning/ref/rlddpgagentoptions.html#mw_b3faa343-570b-4fbf-b3a7-4ba50060537e) "During training, the agent updates the actor and critic using a mini-batch of experiences randomly sampled from the buffer."

Comment: @Huan unfortunately that doesn't answer the question what exactly is specified as training. Is 'training' the time from the first to the max-step? Is it one episode? When exactly does the agent ask for the mini-batch?

Comment: In DDQN or RL in general, training normally begins after a certain condition is satisfied, i.e after a certain predefined epoch where there is enough experience in the experience buffer. In DDQN specifically, a random mini batch is sampled & that minibatch is sent to the neural network model for training. It will defeat the purpose of having mini batches if training is done per episode.

Comment: I'm totally with you that the minibatch would be obsolete if it was per episode. But its nowhere statet that the batch is sampled when its counter is met. As I find in the source code (rlDQNAgent.m, Line 178) the sampling is triggered after every appending of a new experience

Comment: In DDQN or DQN variants in general, sampling a minibatch from the buffer is per time step but a precondition is that there must be something in the buffer. Training will not start unless there's a minibatch to sample from & sampling can't take place if there's not enough experiences in the buffer. The agent will, most likely, at the beginning not do anything other than just collecting experiences (the actions from the model will be rather random), i.e there will no training of the model's weights until either the buffer is filled or a minibatch can be sampled.